# How to receive notifications when moving Window by mouse?

Tags: cocoa, notifications, nswindow

I tried `-setFrame:display:` and `-windowDidMove:` but they are not sent while moving window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If You want to track `NSWindow` live moving, it's not possible by default You’ll have to do it on your own. It's possible to get notification when `NSWindow` is started to drag (move) with `NSWindowWillMoveNotification` or ended dragging (moving) - `NSWindowDidMoveNotification`.

Take a look at these examples they can help You to solve live window moving problem:

**1. Example:**

> **Description:** Very short category on NSWindow that makes windows post
>   NSWindowDidMove notifications continuously during dragging (much like
>   NSWindowDidResizeNotification behaves). Uses a secondary thread and
>   behavior can be toggled.

[Download link](http://www.sb-software.de/marco/dev/SBSWindowAdditions.zip).

**2. Example:**

[Project download link](http://www.sb-software.de/marco/dev/TrackingAWindowFrame.zip).

Comment: This approach consumes much CPU, i checked it before. I go with mouseDown: and mouseDragged: messages.

Comment: @user486134 That was also in my mind. I'm glad that You solved this. Thanks for sharing Your solution maybe this will be useful for somebody.

Comment: @user486134 how do u achieve it using mouseEvents?

Comment: @user486134 One caveat: mouseDragged does not necessarily mean the NSWindow is being moved. Depends on the NSView inside the window.

Answer (score -1):

You can register an observer for [`NSWindowDidMoveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIJGJIE).