# Draggable NSWindow flickering

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I have created a draggable NSWindow that can be dragged via it's contents. It does not have a title bar (borderless).

The dragging works fine, but there's a flicker every so often. It seems the window is quickly going to some faulty position and then returning to where the mouse is (still holding the mouse down). It also seems to work better on my macbook then on my imac.

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

In the init I have called these two methods:

```
[self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
[self setMovable:YES];
```

These are the variables used:

```
NSPoint currentLocation;
NSPoint newOrigin;
int offsetX,offsetY;
```

And here is the code concerning dragging:

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
}


- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    currentLocation = [self convertBaseToScreen:[self mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]];

    offsetX = currentLocation.x - [self frame].origin.x;
    offsetY = currentLocation.y - [self frame].origin.y;
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    currentLocation = [self convertBaseToScreen:[self mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream]];

    newOrigin.x = currentLocation.x - offsetX;
    newOrigin.y = currentLocation.y - offsetY;

    [self setFrameOrigin:newOrigin];

}
```

**EDIT: OK, so as mentioned this is a transparent borderless NSPanel. And yes, I don't seem to need the code above.**

BUT, I do need the location of where the window is being dragged and I need it continuously.

If I just get the frame origin like so:

```
self.frame.origin
```

This reports an incorrect number. It appears to take some time before cocoa updates this internal value.

Secondly, the panel is non-activating. It works fine when moving it the first time it's loaded (focused) and mouseDragged is being called. But not when I interact with another app and then return. Only mouseDown and mouseUp are being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get a NSWindowDidMove notificition **but not live**.

if you need live updates, this isn't possible by default AFAIK. same as *during* a resize, the frame is not updated.

see [How to receive notifications when moving Window by mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495037/how-to-receive-notifications-when-moving-window-by-mouse) for some links on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse tracking code isn't necessary if `-setMovableByWindowBackground:` is getting called; you're basically just duplicating that work. From the sound of it, I'd say your `-init` method isn't getting called, most likely because you're loading from a .xib (which invokes `-initWithCoder:` instead).

If the window is exclusively being created by xib loading, you replace all the above code with just this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
}
```

As for why you were seeing a flicker, my best guess is that it's because mouse input isn't synchronized to the screen refresh, so programmatically making a window follow the mouse is a bit more complex than just updating with each mouse move. But if you let NSWindow take care of it for you, you don't need to worry about that at all.

Comment: Incidentally, `[self setMovable:YES]` is also unnecessary unless you've set it to NO elsewhere -- the default is YES.

Comment: AFAIK, it is necessary to (re)-implement the mouse tracking/moving code for windows that use `NSBorderlessWindowMask`. It looks like that code is based on Apple's `RoundTransparentWindow` sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Listings/Classes_CustomWindow_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000401-Classes_CustomWindow_m-DontLinkElementID_8. I also think that the `initWithCoder:` thing holds true for just about everything except `NSWindow`, as it doesn't support `<NSCoding>`.

Comment: That is correct, it is a transparent borderless window. Sorry for not mentioning that! However, it does seem to work (move) without the mousedragged / mousedown code. But the reason I had that code in the first place was to do something with the location of the drag whilst it's being dragged. And cocoa doesn't seem to report the frame origin correctly whilst dragging (it lags a bit in reporting the correct number). I'll update my question in five minutes with some more info.